# Undefined variable: window in my script?

Tags: javascript, php, yii

I have this error:

> PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException
>
> Undefined variable: window
>
> **function inViewport($el) {**

Part of my code:

```
<?php
$lazyload = <<< JS
$(function() {
  var $window = $(window),
      images = [],
      imagesToBeLoaded = 0,
      i,
      src;

  function throttle(func, wait) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
      var context = this, args = arguments;
      if(!timeout) {
        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
          timeout = null;
        }, wait);
        func.apply(context, args);
      }
    };
  }

  function inViewport($el) {
    var top = $window.scrollTop(),
        left = $window.scrollLeft(),
        bottom = top + $window.height(),
        right = left + $window.width(),
        offset = $el.offset(),
        thisTop = offset.top,
        thisLeft = offset.left,
        thisBottom = thisTop + $el.outerHeight(),
        thisRight = thisLeft + $el.outerWidth();

                      ...

JS;
$this->registerJs($lazyload, View::POS_READY);
?>
```

Why this error is?
In codepen all works fine [Codepen](http://codepen.io/rubinchyk/pen/rdEaK)

Answer (score 4):

Quote the name of the heredoc to prevent PHP from interpreting `$window` as a variable:

```
<?php
$lazyload = <<< 'JS'
...
JS;
```

(see http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc)